# INSERT Data From One Table Into Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-migration

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

I am migrating data over from a current database (single table) to a new database (normalized - many tables). In the new database, I have a base table (let's call it "BaseTable"), and multiple other tables (let's call them `"DependentA"`, and `"DependentB"`). Some of the data from the old database will go to BaseTable, and some will go to the other two. BaseTable has a one-to-one relationship with both DependentA and DependentB, using the Id of them as the foreign key.

So here's my question. How should I migrate the data over? Here is a query I've been trying, which is working except for one thing: the foreign keys in BaseTable for the other two are identical, instead or having a different one each.

```
Begin SQL:

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @dep1Id int

DECLARE @dep2Id int

INSERT INTO DependentA (column1, column2)
SELECT c1, c2
FROM OldDatabase.OldTable
SELECT @dep1Id = Scope_Identity()

INSERT INTO DependentB (column3, column4)
SELECT c3, c4
FROM OldDatabase.OldTable
SELECT @dep2Id = Scope_Identity()

INSERT INTO BaseTable (column5, dependentTable1Id, dependentTablr2Id)
SELECT c5, @dep1Id, @dep2Id
FROM OldDatabase.OldTable

COMMIT
```

Comment: Do any of the columns in the dependent tables hold unique values that could be looked-up? (i.e. c1 & c3)

Comment: There is a primary key in those tables (DependentA and DependentB).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that @dep1Id and @dep1Id are scalar and are retaining the last value only from the two set based inserts.

Since it's a one off you should probably do it as a cursor

```
DECLARE CURSOR @curs FOR
SELECT c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 FROM OldDatebase

open @curs
fetch next from @curs into
@c1,@c2,@c3,@c4,@c5 --declare these!

while @@fetch_status <> 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO DependentA (column1, column2) VALUES @c1, @c2

SELECT @dep1Id = Scope_Identity()

INSERT INTO DependentB (column3, column4) VALUES @c3, @c4 

SELECT @dep2Id = Scope_Identity()

INSERT INTO BaseTable (column5, department1Id, department2Id) @c5, @dep1Id, @dep2Id    

fetch next from @curs into
@c1,@c2,@c3,@c4,@c5
END
close @curs
deallocate @curs
```

My cursor syntax is probably riddled with errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: cursor is not feasible for large data set even worst for me with 261000 rows

Answer (score 4):

To avoid a cursor for large data sets, temporarily include the OldTable_id in the new tables.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO DependentA (OldTable_id, column1, column2)
SELECT ot.id, ot.c1, ot.c2
FROM OldDatabase.OldTable ot

INSERT INTO BaseTable (OldTable_id, column5)
SELECT ot.id, ot.c5
FROM OldDatabase.OldTable ot

UPDATE BaseTable 
    SET BaseTable.dependentTable1_id = DependentA.id
    FROM BaseTable
    INNER JOIN DependentA on DependentA.OldTable_id = BaseTable.OldTable_id

COMMIT
```

Do the same for DependentB table and any other tables being normalized out of the OldTable.

Delete OldTable_id after the data migration.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here][1]ZeorOne is the main table from which you want to get data and insert it into zero and one table respectively.

```
select idzero,namezero,idone,nameone from zeroone

insert into zero 
select idzero,namezero from zeroone

insert into one
select idone,nameone from zeroone
```

or you want to use cursor to insert data  with selected columns from Zeroone 
into to two tables the query is here

```
Declare @idzero int
Declare @namezero varchar(50)
Declare @idone int
Declare @nameone varchar(50)

Declare Cur Cursor  for
select idzero,namezero,idone,nameone from zeroone

open Cur

fetch Cur into @idzero,@namezero,@idone,@nameone

While @@fetch_status = 0
begin 

    insert into zero 
    select @idzero,@namezero 

    insert into one
    select @idone,@nameone 

    fetch Cur into @idzero,@namezero,@idone,@nameone

end 

close Cur
Deallocate Cur
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this answer, to a 7 years old post adds much value to the thread ...

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Product_Name varchar(50),@Generic_Name varchar(50),@Category_Name varchar(50),@Manufacture_Name varchar(50),
@UOM_Name varchar(50),@ProductId int,@GenericId int,@CategoryId int,@ManufactureId int,@UOMId int

DECLARE MultiplTable CURSOR FOR
SELECT ProductName,GenericName,CategoryName,ManufacturerName,UOMName from Noor_ProductList

open MultiplTable
fetch next from MultiplTable into
@Product_Name,@Generic_Name,@Category_Name,@Manufacture_Name,@UOM_Name --declare these!

while @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Noor_GenericMaster(GenericName) VALUES (@Generic_Name) 
SELECT @GenericId = Scope_Identity()

INSERT INTO Noor_CategoryMaster(CategoryName) VALUES (@Category_Name) 
SELECT @CategoryId = Scope_Identity()

INSERT INTO Noor_ManufaturerMaster(ManufaturerName) VALUES (@Manufacture_Name) 
SELECT @ManufactureId = Scope_Identity()

INSERT INTO Noor_UOMMaster(UOMName) VALUES (@UOM_Name)
SELECT @UOMId = Scope_Identity()

INSERT INTO Noor_ProductMaster (ProductName,GenericID,CategoryID,ManufaturerID,UOMID)
values (@Product_Name,@GenericId,@CategoryId,@ManufactureId,@UOMId)
SELECT @ProductId = Scope_Identity()  

fetch next from MultiplTable into @Product_Name,@Generic_Name,@Category_Name,@Manufacture_Name,@UOM_Name

END
close MultiplTable
deallocate MultiplTable
```