# INSERT Data From One Table Into Multiple Tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for an example query that will allow me to insert data from a table into multiple(2) tables.
I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240960/insert-data-from-one-table-into-multiple-tables) but it is for Microsoft SQL Server only and am not sure if this is how you do it in MySQL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just doing it twice would probably be the easiest way

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK mysql doesn't provide a way for inserting data into multiple tables in one command.

You have to use multiple commands, but you may lock table before using them to assure data integrity.

Comment: Why would you need to lock the table?

Comment: Lets say he would be inserting 100k records and he will want to prevent user from adding records to `t2` so the data will be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use multiple query/commands in order to insert into multiple tables.

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl1");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1);

$item1 = $result['item1'];
$item2 = $result['item2'];

$save_to_tbl2 = ("INSERT INTO tbl2(item1,item2)VALUES('".$item1."','"item2."')";
$save = mysql_query(save_to_tbl2);

$save_to_tbl3 = ("INSERT INTO tbl3(item1,item2)VALUES('".$item1."','"item2."')";
$save = mysql_query(save_to_tbl3);
```