# Effective way to move data from one table into multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have TableA that has millions of records and 40 columns.

I would like to move:
- columns 1-30 into Table B
- columns 31-40 into Table C

[This multiple Insert question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240960/insert-data-from-one-table-into-multiple-tables) shows how I would assume I should do it
 `INSERT INTO TableB (col1, col2, ...)
SELECT c1, c2,...
FROM TableA...`

I wanted to know if there was a different/quicker way I could pass the data. Essentially, I don't want to wait for One table to finish Insert processing before the other Insert statement starts to execute

Comment: What is the reason for which you want to split the table?

Comment: Its past of a larger process and all the data gets brought into this "Temp" TableA the next step is take the finished TableA data and push it to the correct final tables (TB and TC). 
There is no way to push the source data to final tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way in the SQL standard to have what is often called a T junction at the end of an INSERT .. SELECT. This, I'm afraid, is the privilege of ETL tools. But the ETL tools connect twice to the database, once for each leg of the T junction, and the resulting two `INSERT INTO tab_x VALUES (?,?,?,?)` statements run in parallel.

Which brings me to a possible solution that could make sense:

Create two scripts. One goes `INSERT INTO table_b1 SELECT col1,col2 FROM table_a;`. One goes `INSERT INTO table_b2 SELECT col3,col4 FROM table_a;`. Then, as it's SQL server, launch two isql sessions in parallel, each running their own script.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... "Then, as it's SQL server, launch two isql sessions in parallel, each running their own script." Are we assuming the MAXDOP is NOT = 1?

Comment: Well, yes. That's the only way I can see two tables being filled at the same time. You need two threads, each writing into a different tablespace, in parallel. If there *were* an INSERT .. SELECT with a T junction at the end, both writing activities would have to run in their own separate thread, too .

Comment: I must admit that I haven't studied the SQL Server specifics enough to understand whether a) MAXDOP controls how many active sessions can run in parallel, or if b) it controls how many processors can be used by one running SQL request. So take what I just said with a grain of salt. If a) is true, then you must change MAXDOP to something else than 1. If b) is true, it should not matter.

Comment: You could change it on your actual query. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx